# What's the most efficient way to search multiple MySQL tables for a large quantity of terms?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Taking a PHP array of terms with variable length (i.e. it could be 50 terms, it could be 400), what's the most efficient way of searching my database for each of these terms?

The search I'm trying to do is quite straightforward. For each term, I'd like to do:

```
SELECT id, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE %term%
```

Obviously I can run a `foreach` in PHP and run multiple MySQL queries, but I'd imagine this to be hugely inefficient.

The code I've most recently tried involves multiple `OR` statements, but with ~100ish terms it appears to run very slowly.

I have no idea if something like this would work?

```
SELECT id, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE %term1%, %term2%, %term3%, %term4%, [...]
```

Can I use a more efficient SQL statement, or should I be looking at this in a different way?

Comment: MySql's search really sucks, even though if you use Fulltext search you won't get what you need. I recommend using Lucene or Solr if you can.

Comment: I agree - Full-text may not give you what you want and does take a lot of effort to get it right... as above suggests do this if you can. Otherwise just make sure you're indexing is correct and try Full-text :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock MySQL could handle this kind of search using

```
MATCH (post_title) AGAINST ('term1 term2 term3 term4')
```

To do this search you will need to add Full Text index into the table using

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_key1(post_title);
```

This would be way faster than LIKE %term%, but please note that Full-Text indexes are only supported in MyISAM tables (InnoDB supported this syntax since MySQL 5.6).

However as your data grow bundled MySQL search speed might become an issue. In this case I would suggest to use external search engine like Solr or Sphinx.

If you decided to switch to Sphinx you may want to take a look on this guide http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional index holding a single column where you simply concatenate the values of all table columns you want to query during the search. This way you can use a single SELECT query with a LIKE clause to search through all columns at once.

This is often referred to as "full text search".

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL the most efficient way is to set up Full-text searching... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its any more efficient than the other suggestions but you could also do

```
SELECT id, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(post_title, '%term1%, %term2%, %term3%, %term4%') <> 0
```